# How to get user's preferred language in Django?

Tags: django, internationalization, locale

I need to know the user's preferred language—preferrably without having to parse the HTTP Accept-Language header myself. The only reason I need it is to return a list of month names localized for their preferred language in an AJAX call. My application has no other needs for internationalization.

```
def ajax_get_month_names(request):

    # Get the user's preferred language

    # Get and return the month names using Python's locale features (pretty easy)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a language code try this code:

```
from django.utils.translation import get_language_from_request
language = get_language_from_request(request)
```